# How to add icon next to WP post title based on custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a little icon (jpg) next to every WordPress posts' titles that have a specifc custom field. Anyone would know how to do it?

I have defined a custom field for some posts like this: $custom = 2 and i want these posts' titles to include an icon.

Answer (score 0):

So to access the specific custom field, use this:

```
get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```

Where $post_id = the id of the post (use

```
$post->ID
```

to get a post's ID)

Where $key = the name of the custom field (ie. "custom")

where $single = If set to true then the function will return a single result, as a string

So you'd use something like:

```
$key = 'custom';
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true) == 2){
    //echo icon here
}
```

You can also check out Wordpress's article on it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: Thanks Kimberly, I know how to call it but can't figure out how to place the icon  to wp titles as default.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by default...if you add that code to your template, and then echo the image for the icon in the space provided, it will show the icon before those posts.

Comment: But where to put above code (in functions.php) and how to call the image?